# I still get the pyramid of doom when using promises, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am using the [Inquirer](https://github.com/sboudrias/Inquirer.js) library with Node.js and I still get the pyramid of doom when using promises, what am I doing wrong?

Just FYI the inquirer library API is basically:

```
inquirer.prompt([
question1,
question2,
question3,
...
questionX
]).then(function(answers){});
```

where answers is a hash, with keys that represent each question. Nothing really out of the ordinary here.

Anyway, using the API, I always get `getAnswersToPrompts().then(function(answers){})` and it seems more convenient to keep nesting the promises inside the previous one...like so:

```
function run (rootDir) {

  return watchHelper().then(function (answers) {

    return chooseDirs({

      allowDirs: answers.allow,
      originalRootDir: rootDir,
      onlyOneFile: false

    }).then(function (pathsToRun) {

      assert(pathsToRun.length > 0, ' You need to select at least one path.');

      return getOptions(availableOptionsForPlainNode).then(function (answers) {

        const selectedOpts = answers[ 'command-line-options' ];

        return localOrGlobal().then(function (answers) {

          const sumanExec = answers.localOrGlobal;

          console.log(' => ', colors.magenta.bold([ '$', sumanExec, '--watch', pathsToRun, selectedOpts ].join(' ')));


        });

      });

    });

  }).catch(rejectionHandler);

}
```

I could possibly do this instead:

```
function run(){

  return makePromise()
    .then(fn1(data1))
    .then(fn2(data2))
    .then(fn3(data3))

}
```

where fn1,fn2,fn3 look like:

```
function fnX(data){

   return function(answers){

      return promise(data);

   }
}
```

but this just makes things more complicated to understand AFAICT

Just be as clear as possible, I definitely need the result of the previous promise, but sometimes I need the result from the promise prior to that or even the result prior to that.

Nesting the functions allows the data I need to be in scope, thanks to closures etc.

Comment: an upvote for using the term "pyramid of doom"

Comment: LOL I don't really mind nested calls, but just curious if there is a way around it

Comment: Have you tried `async` module with its `async.waterfall`? This would be more cleaner in your case.

Comment: yes, I love async more than promises, but the library I am using is 100% promises (the library is called Inquirer) so I should try to work with promises...

Comment: Why is it more complex? Seems straightforward to me

Comment: Don't call then directly on getOptions and localOrGlobal. You can continue in the same level of the chain all the way through (no nesting) as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry didn't answer the last part. It is completely allowed to have a set of variables before the promise chain that are set during the chain. So you can easily use variables that were set in the first part later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return the next Promise *before* calling `then`:

```
function run (rootDir) {
  var pathsToRun;

  return watchHelper()
    .then(function (watchHelperAnswers) {
      return chooseDirs({
        allowDirs: watchHelperAnswers.allow,
        originalRootDir: rootDir,
        onlyOneFile: false
      });
    }).then(function (chooseDirsResult) {
      assert(chooseDirsResult.length > 0, ' You need to select at least one path.');
      pathsToRun = chooseDirsResult;
      return getOptions(availableOptionsForPlainNode);
    }).then(function (getOptionsAnswers) {
      const selectedOpts = getOptionsAnswers[ 'command-line-options' ];
      return localOrGlobal();
    }).then(function (localOrGlobalAnswers) {
      const sumanExec = localOrGlobalAnswers.localOrGlobal;
      console.log(' => ', colors.magenta.bold([ '$', sumanExec, '--watch', pathsToRun,
        selectedOpts ].join(' ')));
    }).catch(rejectionHandler);
}
```

> but sometimes I need the result from the promise prior to that or even the result prior to that

The only instance of this in your example is `pathsToRun`. I think nesting functions two or three deep to accommodate this is still readable, but your other option is to define a variable outside the promise chain, which I have shown above for `pathsToRun`.

Lastly, your example uses three different variables all called `answers` throughout the promise chain, which might be adding to the confusion. In general I think it is fine to use the same name for promise callback results, but I have renamed them here for clarity in this answer.

Comment: nice, thanks, of course! congrats on hitting 20k with this answer :)

Comment: I added an answer that should avoid that side assignment to "pathsToRun" etc.

Comment: re: "The only instance of this in your example is pathsToRun." ...there are actually two instances in the original code, (which I haven't changed), "pathsToRun" AND "selectedOpts". My answer below should avoid side effects in functions, by always returning a new object in each promise that represents accumulated answers, kinda neat actually.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe Daley's answer is near perfect, but to add one more thing. I really don't like that side assignment to variables at the top of the function. I never liked it with async.waterfall/async.series...and I don't like it with promises either...the following pattern should avoid that. We accumulate the data in each promise callback, and then in the final promise callback we have all the data.

```
//start 

    function run (rootDir) {
    
      return watchHelper()
         .then(watchHelperAnswers => {
          
          return chooseDirs({
            allowDirs: watchHelperAnswers.allow,
            originalRootDir: rootDir,
            onlyOneFile: false
          });
    
        })
        .then(chooseDirsResult => {
        
         return getOptions(availableOptions).then((options) => {
              return {       //accumulate answers
                 options: options,
                 pathsToRun: chooseDirsResult
               }
         });
      
        })
        .then((obj) => {
          
          return localOrGlobal().then(answers => {
                return Object.assign(obj,{   //accumulate answers
                     localOrGlobal: answers.localOrGlobal
                  });
          });
        
        }).then((obj) => {
          
          const {...allTheAnswers} = obj;

        }).catch(rejectionHandler);
    }
```

boom! Now you can avoid that awkward assignment to variables at the top. If you don't see how this works...ask me.

Comment: You wanted to avoid the pyramid of doom, because it's not readable and more complexe, but with this solution it's even more complexe. You have to modify functions signatures to accept and return an additional parameter that are not even used in the functions.